# Using Regex or StringTokenizer inline with Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

To parse a log file, I have the following:

```
 try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(logFileName))) {

   List<LogMessage> sm = stream
          .map(line -> new LogMessage(...))  <-- fill in a data extracted from the line in the log file
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
        ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ...
    }
```

There are two possible solutions to extract data from a log message. One is to use StringTokenizer. A sample of using it with Stream is on http://www.baeldung.com/java-stringtokenizer. A problem is that I only need some selected data in a log message, but not all data. For example, in a log message

```
09-Nov-2017 11:54:27.529 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
```

I only need the time stamp (09-Nov-2017 11:54:27.529), the log level (INFO), and a log message (Apache Tomcat/8.5.23).

The another one is to use Regex. But, how to use Regex in the inline form?

Comment: [*`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the java.util.regex package instead.*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info.By using the split method, I get an array. How to extract the data in selected elements of an array?

Comment: I know it doesn't help you one bit, but depending on what you';re doing you may be much faster at doing it in bash rather than in Java. Bash can be very powerful for manipulating log files even with limited bash skills like mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<LogMessage> sm = stream
      .map(s -> s.split(" ", 6))
      .map(a -> new LogMessage(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[5]))
      .collect(toList());
```

Note the use of the extra numeric parameter to `split()`, which limits the number of elements in the result to 6, which leaves the message intact.

This assumes a constructor that looks like:

```
public LogMessage(String date, String time, String level, String message) { ...
```

You can fill in the rest.

Comment: That works great. There is a problem, however, The message portion can contain one or more blank spaces.

Comment: @vic if you actually read my *whole* answer, you'll see I've factored that in.

Comment: Thanks again. After some discussion, I am going to look into JSon format log file output configuration. In the way, I don't even need to parse log files at all.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @Bohemian works fine, but the OP asked for an inline RegEx solution as well.  This can be made as follows:

```
Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(logFileName));

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\S+ \\S+) (\\S+) \\S+ \\S+ (.*)");

List<LogMessage> sm = stream
      .map(pattern::matcher)
      .filter(Matcher::matches)
      .map(m -> new LogMessage( m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3)))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that this will create a new `Matcher` object for each and every line in your log file.  If you a processing a log file with hundreds of thousand lines, a lot of temporary matcher objects are being created and abandoned to the garbage collector.

It is possible to reuse a `Matcher` object by calling the `Matcher#reset(String)` method, passing in the new subject for the next regex match.  The method returns the matcher object itself, so that the method can be chained, like `if (matcher.reset(line).matches()) { ... }`.  We can abuse this signature to create a `String -> Matcher` mapping.  Thus, the above could be rewritten as:

```
Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(logFileName));

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\S+ \\S+) (\\S+) \\S+ \\S+ (.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matches("");

List<LogMessage> sm = stream
      .map(matcher::reset)
      .filter(Matcher::matches)
      .map(m -> new LogMessage( m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3)))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This may be thought of as a **hack**, saving the construction of hundreds of thousands of temporary `Matcher` objects, or the ultimate **evil** using side-effects in stream pipelines.  Premature optimization is the root of all evil, so only use this technique if it can be shown that this pipeline is actually worth optimizing.